# C++ , variables , abstract/ virtual class

Tags: c++, virtual, abstract

Please help me, i'm pretty new to objective C++ and i do not know how to get to variable inicjatywa correctly.
I do not know what is wrong. It is possible that i do not fully understand virtual and abstract classes so i would be greatfull for explaining my mistake.
I want program to output  the value of inicjatywa ( value = 5) from my object Wolf, using the pointer from Organizmy class.

```
class Organizmy
{
public:
int inicjatywa;
virtual void akcja() = 0;
virtual void kolizja() = 0;
virtual void rysowanie() = 0;
virtual ~Organizmy(){};
};

class Animal: public Organizmy
{
public:
    int inicjatywa;
    virtual void akcja() = 0;
    virtual void kolizja() = 0;
    virtual void rysowanie() = 0;
    virtual ~Animal(){};

};

class Wolf: public Animal
{
public:
    int inicjatywa;

    Wolf(){
        cout << "Crate Wolf" << endl;
        this->inicjatywa = 5;
    };
    ~Wolf(){};
    void akcja(){};
    void kolizja(){};
    void rysowanie(){
        cout << "W" << endl;
        cout << this->inicjatywa << endl; // here he output 5 
    };
};
int main()
{
    Organizmy *b;     // I create new poiter; type Organizmy
    b=new Wolf();     // He is now pointing new object Wolf
    b->rysowanie();   // here he outputs correct value of the new elemnt 
    cout<<b->inicjatywa<< endl; //but here the code outputs -8421.... 
                                //and it should be 5 not -8421....

}
```

Comment: ??? Please read the editing-help (the question-mark in the editor shows it), especially the part about formatting code. And I have no idea what your question might be?

Comment: Objective-C or C++. Which one actually? _"and i do not know how to get to variable inicjatywa correctly ..."_ I don't even get it's semantics correctly, so how should I help?

Comment: A [minimal sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in english, and a description of your particular error messages/inputs/expected outputs would improve your question a lot.

Comment: Thank's for advice how to correctly ask questions, it is my first one here so i will improve , but still i need help with it ;/

Comment: @Bliseq Well,you already have a chance to improve with this one, by editing it along the advice I gave you.

Comment: I already change most of it in Eanglish left only what is need, i have no errors so i don't put any of them,  i have no input only output and i wrote it there so what else could i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.  First name your functions sensible things, those names are gibberish and mean nothing to anyone on here.

Second, you're error is quite simple.  The "Wolf" and "Animal" class do not need to re-declare "inicjatywa," so long as they declare their inheritance of "Organizmy" to be public (as they have) the 'outside world' will see all the public elements of "Organizmy."  The code will look like this:

```
class Organizmy
{
public:
    int inicjatywa;
    virtual void akcja() = 0;
    virtual void kolizja() = 0;
    virtual void rysowanie() = 0;
    virtual ~Organizmy(){};
};

class Animal: public Organizmy
{
    public:
    virtual void akcja() = 0;
    virtual void kolizja() = 0;
    virtual void rysowanie() = 0;
    virtual ~Animal(){};
};

class Wolf: public Animal
{
public:

    Wolf(){
        cout << "Crate Wolf" << endl;
        inicjatywa = 5;
    };
    ~Wolf(){};
    void akcja(){};
    void kolizja(){};
    void rysowanie(){
        cout << "W" << endl;
        cout << inicjatywa << endl; // here he output 5 
    };
};
int main()
{
    Organizmy *b;     // I create new poiter; type Organizmy
    b=new Wolf();     // He is now pointing new object Wolf
    b->rysowanie();   // here he outputs correct value of the new elemnt 
    cout<<b->inicjatywa<< endl; //but here the code outputs -8421.... 
                            //and it should be 5 not -8421....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , i'm sorry for those names, i program in my native language , i will try better next time Is there anything else i should think of next time if i wanna get help?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that would make more sense....come to think of it, I don't think I've ever seen code written in something other than English....the only other thing I will say it do not overuse virtual functions (it doesn't appear that you are here) As an example, suppose you had a "getWeigth()" function.  This will be the same for all Organizmy objects, and would not need to be overloaded because the implementation is shared between Wolf, Animal and Organizmy.  You use of virtual in the code provided appears to be adequate.